# How to run Java Code with html..?

Tags: java, html, web

I am starting to build my first website with Angular&Bootstrap. I am using the Spring Tool Suite. So far my website looks pretty boring but learning CSS takes me a while.
On my website I have an input (style=file) and a button to submit. So far I managed to press a button to upload a file. I can see is as a String in the console when I log it, its working.

Now to the point where I need help:
I got a java-program that I have to use which gets the path to an XML-File and parses it. It checks if it has the right special format and reads it in. This is only a part of the whole program. 
How can I use this in my Code to upload an XML-File and then check it and read it with this program? How do I use the Java-Code? So far I am only using HTML, CSS and Javascript.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: why can't you read a tutorial instead of asking to be fed with a silver spoon here?

Comment: @Felix Ludwig Can you tell us how you wanted to read XML file, as text file or you wanted to read the data inside XML tags only ?

Answer (score 2):

There are two options precisely available for you:
1) convert the logic which is in Java to Java script 
Or
2) make it a web application and run it on tomcat(or a similar web server)

There are others too but there are a bit heavy to understand and implement.

Comment: Hey, 2) seems quite fitting, but I do not have any experience regarding to this. For my project I have to use a web server anyway, can you tell me the steps I have to do?

Comment: @felix Ludwig - there are many ways to create web application. I recommend starting here http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnadr.html. Also you can search Google,there are a lot(cannot count) of tutorials available.

Comment: @FelixLudwig  You cannot use 2nd option because you can not get the local filepath because it is useless on the server-side. It would only be of use to hackers. That's why browsers don't send it. But you can go with option 1